# Manipulate Helm chart values (not `values.yaml`) at installation time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Has anyone figured out any way to manipulate the chart (not `values.yaml`) when installing Helm charts?

For example, I have a bash script that basically does

```
helm3 upgrade --install <options>
```

Regardless of whatever the value of `resources.limits.cpu` is in any of my charts, I want to set it to a specific value when installing any charts. If all my charts were using `{{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}` I could use `--set` but my charts are inconsistent. Long term, proper solution is to have consistent charts, but I'm looking for a quick and dirty way.

Comment: Are you trying to adjust settings in the output of the chart, because the input values don't have a consistent format?

Comment: Yes, I guess you could say that.

Comment: Helm has a [post-rendering hook](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering) that is supposed to be able to do that, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change it with helm. But you could try using mutating webhook like the one here: https://github.com/garethr/kubernetes-webhook-examples/blob/master/src/app.py#L38-L41 to alter pods spec in flight as they are being created.

But if you are not using any helm specific features and use it only as templating engine, you can try the following quick and dirty hack:

```
helm template  . | yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[].resources.limits.cpu = "123"' /dev/stdin
```

Notice the use of [helm template](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) (to render templates) an [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (to change limit values)